# What kind of papers do economics and finance students write?

Tags: writing, economics, finance

I teach a writing course that has many students who plan to study economics or finance in graduate school. I am not so familiar with these disciplines, but want to make sure these students finish the semester with the skills they need to succeed in graduate school. What kind of writing assignments can they expect to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a teacher of graduate-level finance classes, the main writing they are expected to perform are business reports and essays. I find that writing essays is easier for them but it is quite common for students to have challenges writing business reports (using bullet points properly, using graphics properly, using section headings and very concise writing properly).

As far as key skills you should be thinking about, the biggest ones are:

- How to construct a proper argument using academic evidence (reasonable sources as opposed to some random person's blog
- The ability to properly cite the work of others (related to the point above)
- Including counter-arguments in their work (another extension of the first point)

If all my graduate students had these skills, my life would be much easier.

Answer (score 4):

[Economical Writing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1577660633) is one standard reference for economists. An economics paper usually has a lit review, an economic model, analysis of what this model predicts, and how the data supports this model. A great outline is provided by the [Toilet Seat Equilibrium](https://www.msu.edu/~choijay/etiquette.pdf) paper.

Your students might want to look at the [Research Papers in Economics](http://repec.org) archive, pick some papers there, and critique them from the intensive writing perspective. This collection has both published and unpublished versions, so with some luck they might be able to trace as the paper is getting into a more publishable state as it moves between versions and revisions.

Answer (score 3):

I ma sure someone can write a more thorough answer, but the following are some resources that may help:

Duke University's ["A Guide to Writing in Economics"](http://lupus.econ.duke.edu/ecoteach/undergrad/manual.pdf)

Charles Sturt's ["Business and Report Writing Skills"](http://www.csu.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/51934/Business-Report-Writing-Skills.pdf)